# How to enable "Change Date and Time" Windows 10v1709

Tags: windows-10, time

In Settings->Time & Language->Date & Time , the 'Change' button is greyed out and a red 'Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization' appears.  This Windows 10 Pro v1709 PC is joined to a domain.  I've created the following Domain GPO and the test machine has no local Group Policies :

Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / User Rights Assignment / Change the system time -> Set the current user and some others.

I've ran 'gpupdate /force' and logged out/in , ran 'gpresult /h C:/gpresult.html' to confirm that the GPO was present.
Based on Internet research, I also tried :
Disabling the NLA service. (no difference, and this is a useful service)
Increasing the Feedback & diagnostics->Telemetry->Diagnostic Data sent back to MS.  (already on the highest level)

Administrators can change the system date / time in Control Panel, but I'd like to do it in Settings, and I'd like regular users to be able to do it.  Perhaps v1803 will give more options.

Comment: Domain policies override local policies.

Comment: Yeah, I can't tell if you are doing that policy as a Domain policy or a Local policy. Please clarify.

Comment: I adjusted the question; it's a domain policy and no local policies are in place.

Comment: For security reasons, date-time is among the settings locked in some corporate environments. If your IT admin wants them locked, either get her or him to change it (or to allow you to change it), or leave them *alone*. Violating policy can cost a job.

Comment: So Windows 10 is a little strange.  It will display this message if something else is disabled, that needs to be enabled.  'I'd like regular users to be able to do it. Perhaps v1803 will give more options." Unlikely.  The only group policy changes I know about have nothing to do with this setting.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the OP states that he is changing the Domain Policy so he ***is*** an IT admin at least to this extent.

Comment: In a domain, your computer gets its date and time from the domain controller.  You really don't want a domain joined computer with an arbitrarily different time than your AD infrastructure.